# MVC web service + web application design that maximizes code reuse

Tags: web-services, model-view-controller, design-patterns, yii

I am using an PHP MVC framework (Yii, but my question could apply to most MVC frameworks) to create a project that should include a web application (website) and RESTful web service. I am facing an early design decision on how to logically separate the application and service logic. Here are some true facts:

- The web app and web service will share a lot of functionality and only differ in rendered format (`View` vs JSON)...
- ...But, the web app and web service will have some unique features (ie, there will be things that the web app does that the service does not, and vice-versa)

Here are my desires:

- I would like to share the common functionality's implementation as much as possible
- I do not want the `Controller` to become unwieldy as a result of combining web service/web application logic
- I have a a *slight* distaste for creating separate web service and web app controllers, especially when they overlap in `Action`s (other than the rendered format)
- I do not want to have the web site consume the web service unless it is really a necessary design decision; I will lose out on a lot of built-in features that use database interfaces and/or have to create classes that conform to available `IDataSource` and other such interfaces by hooking it up to the web service; also there could be a slight performance decline.

I have thought about it a bit and come up with some solutions below. Please let me know which of these you think would meet my wants *or* let me know if my wants are not reasonable/counter-productive.

1. Implement completely separate controllers for `WebApp` and `WebService` (modularize the two so that they share no code)
2. Implement separate controllers for `WebApp` and `WebService`, but create methods that do the heavy lifting and call those methods to share implementation - for example, if I wanted to do a `item/findBySomeCrazyCriteria` I would route to the appropriate controller depending on the URL, but each controller would reference some `FindItemsBySomeCrazyCriteriaFunction()` defined elsewhere.
3. Make the web app consume the web service (which would require me to expand the planned functionality of the service)
4. Implement one controller for both `WebApp` and `WebService`, which extends from a `BaseController` that includes generic hooks for `REST` type stuff in terms of $this->getModel()` and use overrides where necessary
5. Anything else

Although my question is related to Yii, I feel like this must have come up in the past for many developers. I would like to know what you did/what you recommend to move forward. I am concerned that if I choose the wrong approach I will "break MVC" or somehow regret it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> <sub>**Note:** you should not worry about "breaking the MVC". Since you have chosen to use Yii, that part has already happened.</sub>

The root of the problem lays in the fact that your controllers do a lot of stuff (and thus, violating [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)). What you call "controllers' actually contain also the application logic (that should be part of model layer) and UI logic (that normally would be part of view instances).

What you should have there is a single application, with one model layer and two presentations (what you refer to as "web application" and "web service"). The controllers should be a slight a possible.

You should move the application logic to the [service layer](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html) through which then the presentation layer would interact with model. You would end up with a lot lighter controller. Then you could be able to provide a separate set of controllers/view for each of the presentations that your project needs with no or minor code duplication.

Comment: Would it be fair to say that the "service layer" you describe can be thought of as a bunch of methods that mimic stored procedures, and the "presentation layers" (html, json, xml, etc) as only accessing the model through methods available in the "service layer" ? ... ie the "service layer" would never be accessible by any client, but would wrap all of the business logic up in neat packages for the other presentation layers to consume?

Comment: No. The "service layer" would actually be made up from a group of classes that are usually responsible for interaction between [domain objcts](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject) and [data mappers](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html). In a fully implemented model layer service as an essential part. But since Yii does not really have a fully implemented model layer, the best you can do is to isolate the interaction of/between your [active record](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) structures.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend against writing multiple controllers. It is a much better option to keep your domain logic in the models, rather than controllers. Your controllers should only act as the gateway to the logic and serve them in whatever form the client requests eg. as a JSON encoded response or through a view. It would be best if you just keep the task of identifying the client requirements and after obtaining the results from the model translating the response in an appropriate form.

This flow can be streamlined with suitable helpers and a well implemented routing sub-system so that detection of client requirements becomes effortless.

eg. `/user/subscriptions.html` will fetch an html page where as `/user/subscriptions.json` will fetch a JSON response.